# несовместимые типы операндов(" int " в (int[3]) )

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
/*
4) **В двумерном массиве найти и вывести на экран максимальные элементы из каждой строки.
*/
const int col = 3;
const int row = 3;
int mas[row][col];
int max = 0;
int max1;
int max2;
srand(time(0));

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        if (mas[j] < max) {
            max = mas[j];
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `mas` - это **двумерный** массив. Значит, `mas[j]` - массив одномерный. Просто подскажите, что вы хотите в сравнении `mas[j] < max` - как на него верно ответить, если `mas[j]` - массив `{1,2,3,4,5}`, а `max` - число 3? :) И как, если потребуется, записать в одну переменную типа `int` несколько? Поочередно? :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Вопроса как такового нет
2. Ты присваиваешь переменной max (ее тип int) указатель на массив mas[j] (поэтому и ошибка)

правильно будет:

```
        if (mas[i][j] < max) {
            max = mas[i][j];
        }
```

А вообще - внимательнее следи за типами (там даже компилятор тебе сказал в чем проблема)